# Typescript - handle empty props in component

Tags: typescript, react-native

How can I handle empty props in my component so it does not show a blank component. Currently I get the error:

```
Type '{ activeBreakdownDescription?: string | undefined; activeBreakdownHeader?: string | undefined; activeBreakdownIcon?: any; activeBreakdownImage?: any; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ activeBreakdownDescription?: string | undefined; activeBreakdownHeader?: string | undefined; activeBreakdownIcon?: any; activeBreakdownImage?: any; }'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ activeBreakdownDescription?: string | undefined; activeBreakdownHeader?: string | undefined; activeBreakdownIcon?: any; activeBreakdownImage?: any; }'.
```

In my header I am passing the following props:

```
<HomeHeader
  dynamicHeroItems={filteredCarouselItems}
  activeBreakdownContent={activeBreakdownContent}
/>
```

How I can check the empty the property exists in the component?

```
interface HomeHeaderProps {
  activeBreakdown: {
    activeBreakdownDescription?: string;
    activeBreakdownHeader?: string;
    activeBreakdownIcon?: BaseImageModel;
    activeBreakdownImage?: BaseImageModel;
  };
}

const HomeHeader = ({
  activeBreakdownContent: {
    activeBreakdownHeader,
    activeBreakdownDescription,
    activeBreakdownIcon,
    activeBreakdownImage,
  },
  dynamicHeroItems,
}: HomeHeaderProps) => {

// ...

if (...) {
  return (
    <RescueMeHero
      title={activeBreakdownHeader || ''}
      body={activeBreakdownDescription || ''}
      image={activeBreakdownImage}
      icon={activeBreakdownIcon}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least 2 options:

1. if the prop is empty, don't have the parent try to render the component:

```
{(filteredCarouselItems && activeBreakdownContent && <HomeHeader
      dynamicHeroItems={filteredCarouselItems}
      activeBreakdownContent={activeBreakdownContent}
    />)}
```

which will only render `<HomeHeader>` if both props have a non-falsey value.

2. Inside HomeHeader, decide what you want to show instead of a blank when the prop is empty:

```js
if (activeBreadownImage && activeBreakdownIcon) {
    return (
      <RescueMeHero
        title={activeBreakdownHeader || ''}
        body={activeBreakdownDescription || ''}
        image={activeBreakdownImage}
        icon={activeBreakdownIcon}
      />
    );
} else {
  return <div>Something Else Goes Here</div>;
}
```